# Did the Zapatistas actually kill anyone?

Tags: revolution, americas, mexico

The armed [Zapatista movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapatista_Army_of_National_Liberation) started in 1994 as an armed revolution and spanned more than [20 years](http://www.casacollective.org/content/timeline-zapatista-movement).

Disambiguation - this is the [1983/1994 movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Zapatista_Army_of_National_Liberation), **not** the [1910 movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_Army_of_the_South).

It is surprising to note that there seem to be no records of them actually killing anyone, while the counter-revolutionary forces have killed several Zapatistas.

> “After they took San Cristobal, the Zapatistas went into combat at the
>   Rancho Nuevo military base, the nearest base to San Cristobal de las
>   Casas. I was there, this photo is mine. They are dead Zapatistas
>   killed in battle. They were also ambushed. When I took this photo, 20
>   or so of them died. They were uniformed, they had been killed barely
>   20 minutes before. We heard the bullets… It was horrible.”

*Citation taken from [this photo report](https://news.vice.com/article/in-photos-zapatista-armys-20-years-of-war) where you can see several pictures of dead Zapatistas. You can also see photos of the guerillas with weapons and practicing.*

However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapatista_Army_of_National_Liberation) and other [articles](http://www.kiptik.org/history.html) such as the one [mentioned earlier](http://www.casacollective.org/content/timeline-zapatista-movement) only claim killing by the army and not the Zapatistas. The Chiapas Movement [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiapas_conflict) does claim that **one soldier** was killed on 2nd February 2011 (all other killed are the Zapatistas).

A [post from 2014](http://www.schoolsforchiapas.org/2014/05/zapatista-teacher-dead/) claims that the media is distorting facts about the conflict and that the Zapatistas have been on the receiving end.

[Subcommandante Marcos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcomandante_Marcos) claims:

> "We didn't go to war to kill or be killed. We went to war in order to
>   be heard."

But it is hard to belive that in 20 years of armed conflict the Zapatistas have not actually attacked or killed anyone (or at least more than the claim of 1 sole soldier).

What is the truth about casualties inflicted by them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiapas_conflict "Military dead: 3". I don't see why this is unbelievable - the stated goal of the Zapatistas is not to overthrow the government in all of Mexico but to be autonomous in their own region. There is no incentive for Zapatistas to attack Military bases just as the regular forces (and their supporting right-wing terrorist groups) have no incentive for combat but are mostly content with evicting families from supposed government property.

Comment: @user45891 however, by their own records combat **did** take place. See the quote above. I find it hard to believe that even retaliatory/defensive fire has killed only 1 (or 3) people over 20 years of armed conflict. I don't say it's untrue- i'm just asking if there are records to explain this number, or any other (higher)number.

Answer (score 2):

> MEXICO CITY — Hundreds of armed Indian peasants attacked four cities and towns in the southeastern state of Chiapas on Saturday. At least three police officers were killed and 18 were wounded, news reports said. *[LATimes](http://articles.latimes.com/1994-01-02/news/mn-7757_1_zapatista-army)*
>
> Rebels held the towns for several days, battling with Mexican troops before withdrawing into the surrounding jungle. More than 100 people were killed in the initial battles. *[Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Zapatista-National-Liberation-Army)*